# Django - sorting a list of results from two QuerySet objects

Tags: database, django

For example, let's assume that i have two QuerySEt objects:

```
queryset1 = my_model1.objects.all().order_by('-created')
queryset2 = my_model2.objects.all().order_by('-created')
```

And i want one list with elements from both querysets, list oreder by '-created' field. Has someone have a recipe for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
newlist = sorted(itertools.chain(queryset1, queryset2),
  key=operator.attrgetter('created'), reverse=True)
```